# How to get multiple Backend User Group Access Lists in Typo3

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to have multiple backend user group access lists in Typo3? For instance, I would like to have an access list at the root level (which seems to be the normal case),

[image: root level access list for be user group]

and another one further down in the page tree. The title in the backend would then look something like:

**Edit Backend usergroup "Author" on folder level**

Is this possible?

Comment: No, it's not possible. If you are trying to fine-tune **access** permissions to pages/branches, then go with the pgampe's answer. Otherwise specify instead what eaxctly you are trying to achieve with your setup and you might get an advice on some different solution or a workaround.

Comment: I would like to create a BE group at any level in the page tree, so that I can set Access Lists on any level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access list are assigned to groups. So this is not possible with a stock TYPO3. However you might want to try the extension [`be_acl`](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/be_acl/).

Comment: This extension gives me the possibility to set privileges for several Groups. However, I can not see how to set ACL's for modules, content etc. using the extension.

Comment: You must create different backend groups for each level than. You can assign individual page mount points to the groups.